# NewtonSoft Json.Net serialiser

Tags: c#, json, serialization, async-await, json.net

I'm just starting to develop more in C# after being mainly a VB.NET developer and was looking for someone to critique my implementation of a NewtonSoft Json.Net serialiser.

Can you provide some feedback on the following points:

1. Is this a good way to build the class (using Unity)?
2. Is it acceptable to be throwing an exception from the constructor?
3. Is the Async/Await implementation correct?

**Interface**

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Helper.Core.Serialisation
{
    public interface ISerialiser
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Serialise the passed in object with the Json.Net serialiser
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Generic type of the serialised object</typeparam>
        /// <param name="serialseObject">The object to be serialised</param>
        /// <returns>A serialised Json string</returns>
        Task<string> SerialiseAsync<T>(T serialseObject);

        /// <summary>
        /// Serialise the passed in object with the Json.Net serialiser and compress the string using the IStreamCompression implementation
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Generic type of the serialised object</typeparam>
        /// <param name="serialseObject">The object to be serialised</param>
        /// <returns>A compressed byte array of the serialised object</returns>
        Task<byte[]> SerailseAndCompressAsync<T>(T serialseObject);

        /// <summary>
        /// Deserialise the Json string into the generic object
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Generic type of the serialised object</typeparam>
        /// <param name="serialseObject">The object to be serialised</param>
        /// <returns>A deserialsied object of type T</returns>
        Task<T> DeserialiseAsync<T>(string serialsedString);

        /// <summary>
        /// Uncompress and deserialise the Json string into the generic object
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Generic type of the serialised object</typeparam>
        /// <param name="serialed">The object to be serialised</param>
        /// <returns>An uncompressed & deserialsied object of type T</returns>
        Task<T> DeserialseAndUnCompressAsync<T>(byte[] serialed);
    }
}
```

**Implementation**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Helper.Core.Compression;
using Helper.Core.Logging;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Helper.Core.Serialisation
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Json.Net implementaiton of the ISerialiser interface
    /// </summary>
    internal class JsonSerialiser : ISerialiser
    {
        private readonly IStreamCompression _streamCompressor;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new instance of the Json.Net Serialiser implementaton
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="streamCompressor">IStreamCompression implementation composed via the IOC container</param>
        /// <param name="logger">ILogger implementation composed via the IOC container</param>    
        [InjectionConstructor]
        public JsonSerialiser(IStreamCompression streamCompressor, ILogger logger)
        {
            if (streamCompressor == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("streamCompressor");
            if (logger == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("logger");

            this._streamCompressor = streamCompressor;
            this._logger = logger;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Serialise the passed in object with the Json.Net serialiser
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Generic type of the serialised object</typeparam>
        /// <param name="serialseObject">The object to be serialised</param>
        /// <returns>A serialised Json string</returns>
        public async Task<string> SerialiseAsync<T>(T serialseObject)
        {
            if (serialseObject == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("serialseObject");

            try
            {
                return await JsonConvert.SerializeObjectAsync(serialseObject);
            }
            catch (JsonSerializationException ex)
            {
                _logger.LogEntry(ex);
                throw new SerialisationException("Could Not Serialse The Object", ex);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Serialise the passed in object with the Json.Net serialiser and compress the string using the IStreamCompression implementation
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Generic type of the serialised object</typeparam>
        /// <param name="serialseObject">The object to be serialised</param>
        /// <returns>A compressed byte array of the serialised object</returns>
        public async Task<byte[]> SerailseAndCompressAsync<T>(T serialseObject)
        {
            if (serialseObject == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("serialseObject");

            try
            {
                string serialised = await SerialiseAsync(serialseObject);
                return await _streamCompressor.CompressStringAsync(serialised);
            }
            catch (StreamCompressionException ex)
            {
                _logger.LogEntry(ex);
                throw new SerialisationException("Could Not Compress The Object", ex);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deserialise the Json string into the generic object
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Generic type of the serialised object</typeparam>
        /// <param name="serialseObject">The object to be serialised</param>
        /// <returns>A deserialsied object of type T</returns>
        public async Task<T> DeserialiseAsync<T>(string serialsedString)
        {
            if (serialsedString == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("serialsedString");

            try
            {
                return await JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<T>(serialsedString);
            }
            catch (JsonSerializationException ex)
            {
                _logger.LogEntry(ex);
                throw new SerialisationException("Could Not Deserialse The Object", ex);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Uncompress and deserialise the Json string into the generic object
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Generic type of the serialised object</typeparam>
        /// <param name="serialed">The object to be serialised</param>
        /// <returns>An uncompressed & deserialsied object of type T</returns>
        public async Task<T> DeserialseAndUnCompressAsync<T>(byte[] serialed)
        {
            if (serialed == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("serialed");

            try
            {
                string decompressedSerialised = await _streamCompressor.DecompressStringAsync(serialed);
                return await DeserialiseAsync<T>(decompressedSerialised);
            }
            catch (StreamCompressionException ex)
            {
                _logger.LogEntry(ex);
                throw new SerialisationException("Could Not Decompress The Object", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with throwing the exception in the constructor.  If the parameter is required, it's required.  At least caught in the constructor you have a chance to review the call stack and find out why

Comment: I agree with dreza , constructing an object should be avoided if some of necessary parameter are not present during constructing an object.

Comment: As all methods in interface has async postfix, maybe rename ISerializer to IAsyncSerializer and remove async postfix in methods names.

Comment: surely it would be better to allow a null stringcompressor/logger rather than throw an exception in a constructor. It seems simple and logical that null wont log or compress?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Code looks good, I like this IoC style.
3 points to your consideration:

1. You should `catch` an `AggregateException` over `await`.
2. I wouldn't bother passing a `logger` to a `serializer` - that's none of his business. Let the serializer `throw` if he's not happy.
3. Fix some typo in names and messages ("Deserialse" and so).
4. I somewhat doubt the whole concept of async serialization. I take serialized data to be an object snapshot in a known 'time point'. But if it's useful for you go for it.

(Oops didn't address your actual questions)

1. Yes I think it's great.
2. Sure. Lacking meaningful 'default object', you don't have many alternatives.
3. This is probably the main issue here, and the hardest to answer. I have some doubts about returning a non-cancellable `Task`. I suspect if the object to be serialized has changed completely, the user may want to cancel the serialization.

Answer (score 0):

A minor point, but what if you want to create a single threaded `Serializer` as well?

I would rename your interface to something like `IAsyncSerializer` so that you could have a different interface `ISerializer`.